# Passing a counter argument to an awk script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a following file named `abc` with a 10 lines of text and a `script.awk` file that prints the output as number of lines to print (like `tail`). In this example it prints last 3 lines but I want a counter to be used as a user input i.e. so I can run:

```
$ awk -f script.awk abc <counter>
```

How can I do it?

**abc**

```
skdns;avbvbkabvbakv 
sad;vn;kns;anv;navvs
skdns;avbvbkabvbakv
sad;vn;kns;anv;navvs
skdns;avbvbkabvbakv
sad;vn;kns;anv;navvs 
skdns;avbvbkabvbakv  
sad;vn;kns;anv;navvs
skdns;avbvbkabvbakv 
sad;vn;kns;anv;navvs
```

**script.awk**

```
{
  arr[NR]=$0
}
END { 
   i=NR-3
   while(i<NR)
   {
       print arr[i+1]
       i++
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you really want a `for` loop here not a `while`:

```
{
    arr[NR]=$0
}    
END {
    for (i=NR-2;i<=NR;i++) {
        print arr[i]
    }
}
```

If you don't need to access the variable in the `BEGIN` block you don't need to use `-v` so you would just do `awk -f file n=3` (any argument passed to `awk` containing an `=` will be treated as a variable). The following will handle if `n` is unset or greater than the number lines in the file:

```
{
    arr[NR]=$0
}    
END {
    n=(n?n:NR)
    n=(n?NR:NR:n)
    for (i=NR-n+1;i<=NR;i++) {
        print arr[i]
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk -f script.awk n=5
6
7
8
9
10

$ seq 1 3 | awk -f script.awk
1
2
3

$ seq 1 3 | awk -f script.awk n=6
1
2
3
```

The final tweak you should make is to not store every line of the file in memory, only store the number of lines you need to print. You can achieve this by using clever indexing with the modulus function `%`.

Comment: Thanks.. but does `n=(n?n:10)` affect if my line more or less than 10??

Comment: @vishalkin yeah `n=(n?n:NR)` is better.

Comment: thanks @sudo_O this is the second time u answered my question...
now i am working with printing 1st **n lines** using awk... hope i succeed.. otherwise i hope you wil be there to help me out...

Comment: @vishalkin first `n` is just `awk 'NR>n{exit}1' file n=10`. Always happy to help.

Comment: i tried it and working fine but its a common syntax that everybody uses.. so trying something different so that i get good marks.. :p

Comment: If it's for an assignment then yes you should write a script with comments, usage, help, useful variable names, make sure you handle all the edge cases ect.

Answer (score 1):

awk has an option '-v variable=value' option to set variables from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `i = NR - j` in your awk script.

Now use this command

```
awk -f script.awk -v j=3 abc
```